# what precautions to take while reapplying UK visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am applying from India to visit my brother in UK. My visa application was rejected in Feb 2019 due to me not attaching my bank or other financial documents since my brother was sponsoring me.  now should I write a detailed note of reason of rejection earlier and the attachments I am submitting for reapplying?

Comment: It is good to read the various rejection answers in this site, and to check what document to include and why. You financial documents are used not only to see if you can afford the travel (without working in UK), but also to see if you have interest on returning home. By having a brother, you may have some thing easier (cheap accommodation/funds), but other more complex (wiliness to return home). Try to better address this later point.

Comment: You don't need to write a detailed note of why you were rejected previously: they already know why. Just acknowledge that your earlier application was rejected for lack of documentation and that you're now including the necessary documents. They have to deal with huge numbers of applications so they don't want you to waste their time by telling them things they already know.